# Topology on $\text{Homeo}(X)$ Which Captures Topological Group Actions.

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

**Definition.** Let $G$ be a group and $X$ be any set.
We may define a **group action** of $G$ on $X$ as map $\cdot: G\times X\to X$ such that $e\cdot x=x$ for all $x\in X$ and $g\cdot(h\cdot x)=gh\cdot x$ for all $g, h\in G$ and $x\in X$ (Here, of course, $g\cdot x$ is just a way of writing $\cdot(g, x)$).

Alternatively, we may equivalently say that a group action of $G$ on $X$ is a group homomorphism $G\to \text{Bijections}(X)$, where $\text{Bijections}(X)$ is the set of all the bijections of $X$ which makes a group under composition (This is the permutation group on $X$. I have avoided the use of the notation $S_X$).

**Definition.** Now suppose $G$ is any group and $X$ be a topological space.
We may say that $G$ acts on $X$ if there is a map $\cdot:G\times X\to X$ such that $\cdot$ is an action when $X$ is considered as a set along with an extra condition that the map $x\mapsto g\cdot x:X\to X$ is continuous for all $g\in G$.

This may again be equivalently phrased as follows: A group action of $G$ on a topological space $X$ is a group homomorphism $G\to \text{Homeo}(X)$, where $\text{Homeo}(X)$ is the set of all the homoemorphism $X\to X$ under composition.

The "alternative descriptions" have a sense of uniformity. In fact, if $X$ is any object, then we may say that an action of $G$ on $X$ is a homomorphism $G\to \text{Aut}(X)$.

**My Question** is the following:

Suppose that $G$ is a topological group, that is, $G$ has a topology under which the binary operation and the inverse map are continuous.
Let $X$ be a topological space.
The standard definition of a **continuous action** of $G$ on $X$ is a continuous map $G\times X\to X$ which is also a group action when $X$ is thought of only as a set.

> What I was wondering is can we give a topology on $\text{Homeo}(X)$ such that a continuous group homomorphisms correspond exactly to continuous actions of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff and $G$ is Hausdorff, the compact-open topology will do the trick (by the exponential law for spaces). In general, $Homeo(X)$ with the compact-open topology is not a topological group though since multiplcation can fail to be continuous.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas We do not need $\text{Homeo}(X)$ to be a topological group. We only need a topology on it such that continuous group homomorphisms (by which I mean a map which is a group homomorphism and is continuous)  correspond to continuous actions of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: In view of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), one might also what topology we put on $\hom$ so that $A\times B\to C$ is continuous iff the corresponding $A\to\hom(B,C)$ is continuous.